# Unbiased Estimator of the Standard Error of another Estimator

Tags: random-variables, parameter-estimation

Suppose that $Y_1,...,Y_n$ is an IID sample from a uniform $U(\theta, 1)$ distribution.  The method of moments estimator for $\theta$ is $\tilde \theta=2\bar Y-1$.  The standard error of $\tilde \theta$ is

$$\sigma_{\tilde \theta}=\frac{1-\theta}{\sqrt{3n}}$$

Find an unbiased estimator of $\sigma_{\tilde \theta}$ and show that it is unbiased.

So normally I know how to find the estimator of a parameter of a distribution, but I don't quite understand **how I'm supposed to find an estimator of the standard deviation of another estimator of a parameter of a distribution**... so I really don't know how to go about this.  What do I do?

Comment: Sorry, but those are all basically given.  I don't understand how those quantities are helping me find this second estimator.

Comment: If you let $\hat{\sigma}_{\tilde{\theta}} = \frac{1-\tilde{\theta}}{\sqrt{3n}}$ and $\tilde{\theta}$ is unbiased, then $\hat{\sigma}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma_{\tilde{\theta}}$. I think $\tilde{\theta} = 1-2\bar{Y}$ might be the correct method of moments estimator, though? Otherwise it's expectation is $-\theta$

Answer (score 2):

My Comment (now deleted) was an attempt, perhaps not well worded, to get you to look carefully
at everything again.

First verify that $E(Y_i) = \frac{\theta + 1}{2}$ and $Var(Y_i) = \frac{(1-\theta)^2}{12},$ so that $E(\bar Y) = \frac{\theta+1}{2},\,$
$Var(\bar Y) = \frac{(1-\theta)^2}{12n}$ and $SD(\bar Y) = \frac{1-\theta}{\sqrt{12n}}.$

Then, setting $\bar Y = \frac{\tilde \theta+1}{2}$ we obtain the MME of $\theta$ as $\tilde \theta = 2\bar Y - 1.$ Morover, $\tilde \theta$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ because $E(2\bar Y - 1) = 2E(\bar Y) -1 = \theta.$
[Earlier typos above fixed, thanks to Comment by @ereHsaWyhsipS.]

As a reality check on the above, I use a simulation of
the special case $\theta = .25,\, n = 10.$

```
set.seed(209)  # retain 'set.seed' to repeat same simulation, omit for fresh simulation
th = 1/4; n = 10
a = replicate(10^6, mean(runif(n, th, 1)))  # one million sample averages
th.mme = 2*a - 1
mean(th.mme);  th
## 0.2499683  # aprx E(MME of theta)
## 0.25       # exact $(MME of theta) = theta, MME unbiased
```

Also $Var (\tilde \theta) = Var(2\bar Y - 1) = 4Var(\bar Y) = \frac{(1-\theta)^2}{3a}$ and $SD(\tilde \theta) = SD(\tilde \theta) = \sigma^* 
= \frac{1-\theta}{\sqrt{3n}}.$ (This is your $\sigma_{\tilde \theta}.)$
Another reality check:

```
sd(th.mme);  (1 - th)/sqrt(3*n)
## 0.136847    # aprx SD(MME of theta)
## 0.1369306   # exact
```

A reasonable first try toward an estimator $\widetilde{\sigma^*}$ of
$\sigma^*$ is simply to use $\tilde \theta$ for $\theta$ in the numerator
to get 
$$\widetilde{\sigma^*} = \frac{1 - \tilde\theta}{\sqrt{3n}}
= \frac{1 - (2\bar Y - 1)}{\sqrt{3n}} = \frac{2(1 - \bar Y)}{\sqrt{3n}}.$$
Then $E(\widetilde{\sigma^*}) = \frac{2 - (1+\theta)}{\sqrt{3n}} = 
\frac{1-\theta}{\sqrt{3n}},$
so that $\widetilde{\sigma^*}$ is unbiased for $\sigma^*.$

```
mean(2*(1-a)/sqrt(3*n))
## 0.1369364     # agrees aprx with above, suggesting sg.mme unbiased
```

Comment: This is a uniform distribution.  The expectation is $\frac{1+\theta}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. Fixing typos. Simulations OK